# Joomla 3 JDatabase how to echo rows

Tags: database, joomla

I can't find valid statement for fetching rows and displaying items in `JDatabase`.

My code looks like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array('item_id, item_name'));
$query->from('#__items');
```

How to print out these items in table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
// Get a database object
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('item_id, item_name');
$query->from('#__items');

// sets up a database query for later execution
$db->setQuery($query);

// fetch result as an object list
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
```

For more detail see the link [Accessing the database using JDatabase/3.0](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/3.0) . For more methods of how to fetch result you can use `loadResult()`,`loadRow()`,`loadAssoc()`,`loadObject()`,`loadResultArray()`,`loadRowList()`,`loadAssocList()`.

You can also refer this [Accessing the database using JDatabase/1.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/1.5) .

You can also refer this link for how to

[Developing a Model-View-Controller Component/3.0/Introduction](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/3.0/Introduction)

[Developing a Model-View-Controller Component/2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Developing_a_Basic_Component)

Hope it help you.

Comment: Thanks. But the question is how to print out those items?

Comment: @MindaugėlisPakasyk If you put these line of code in model function ,then you need to return this result and in view of you component access this element by using foreach loop statement.

Comment: @MindaugėlisPakasyk see my updated answer with link of how to develop mvc component in joomla.

Comment: @MindaugėlisPakasyk You can use it in your component, module, plugin,templates.

Answer (score 4):

The docs page is here: http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/3.0

you need to add something like this:

```
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

This will give you an array of objects where each object is a row.

This page: http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/1.5 is for Joomla! 1.5, but still has (imho) the best list of the possible functions to get your data. Most are still valid I think.

To output the $results array you use something like this:

```
foreach ($results as $row) :
    echo $row->item_id;
    echo $row->item_name;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thanks. But the question is how to print out those items. I cant access the array...

Comment: Updated answer with how to print the items.

Answer (score 0):

You don't add the array to your select query, you simply add the values, separated by a comma, like so:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('item_id, item_name')
$query->from('#__items');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```